# Как посредством css выделить объект, у которого есть дочерние элементы?

Tags: css

Сабж в вопросе. Если стилизировать детей можно банальным X>Y, то вопрос стилизации только тех родителей, у которых есть дети, неожиданно поставил в тупик.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, можно выбрать непустые элементы (**содержащие дочерние элементы, текст или пробелы**).
С помощью псевдоклассов [`:empty`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/empty) и [`:not`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/not). Вот так:

```
.parent:not(:empty) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Не уверен, что вам это подходит на 100%, но в CSS правилах указать на родительский элемент через его дочерние элементы невозможно.

Тем не менее, вы можете добиться желаемого эффекта другим способом.

Допустим, есть такая разметка:

```
<span class="parent">
    <span class="child">1</span>
</span>
<span class="parent">
    <span class="child">1</span>
    <span class="child">2</span>
</span>
```

С помощью псевдокласса [**:only-child**](http://htmlbook.ru/css/only-child) мы можем найти единственный дочерний элемент у родителя, а дальше с помощью абсолютного позиционирования и `z-index` стилизовать такого родителя.

```
.parent {
    border: 1px solid #333; /* По умолчанию граница у родителя серая */
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    background: lightgray; /* По умолчанию фон у дочерних элементов светло-серый */
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
.child:only-child {
    background: yellow; /* У единственного потомка фон желтый */
}

.child:only-child::before {
    border: 1px solid cyan; /* Перекрываем серую границу родителя бирюзовой */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    /* Клики будут проходить сквозь псевдоэлемент */
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* Исправляем смещение, получившееся из-за границы родителя */
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    /* Растягиваем элемент на всю ширину и высоту родителя */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Получится вот что:

[image: Пример]

[**Посмотреть пример**](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/dw7j59zv/)

Дополнительно почитайте вот эту статью (она на английском):

**[Стилизация дочерних элементов на основе их количества](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/)**

Выдержка из нее:

```
/* один элемент */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

/* два элемента */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
    width: 50%;
}

/* три элемента */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
    width: 33.3333%;
}

/* четыре элемента */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Хм, про стилизацию по количеству дочек я знаю, но, тем не менее, ваши рассуждения натолкнули меня на одну весьма занятную идею. Если выгорит, будет праздник.